# Hitting tab is producing a "0" instead of four spaces only on one line in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am very new to programming and using Learn Python The Hard Way.  I'm using Sublime Text 2 and haven't had any problems yet.  Normally to comment I will hit tab a few times after the line of code to line up the comments on the right.  It always works except for the following line.

```
print "OR, we can use variables from our script:"  
amount_of_cheese = 10
amount_of_crackers = 50
```

When I hit tab after **`amount_of_cheese = 10`** it just adds zeros.  I hit tab twice and it became

```
amount_of_cheese = 1000
```

If I keep hitting tab it will delete the last 0 and so on switching from 100 to 1000.
Every other line tabs out fine after the code.

I'm sure this is basic but it is just strange.  What's the problem?

Comment: I think sublimetext just understands that you can always use more cheese.  (And cowbell!)  Seriously, this is strange, +1.

Comment: Yea I don't get it.  I can space and then tab fine, but just a tab is acting like its undoing and redoing zeros.

Comment: It sounds like tab completion gone wrong, lol. Press the right arrow at the end of the 10, then tab.

Comment: If I hit the right arrow it just puts the cursor at the beginning of the next line per usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this out. If you have the numbers 100 or 1000 somewhere else in your file, then typing 10 then TAB is going to act like tab completion. If you type a space then tab it should work.

Comment: Yup that was it.  Worked fine once I got rid of my other 100 and 1000.  Now I know about tab completions. I thought it always displayed it first?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, so did I. Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't for numbers?  Honestly I just started programming so I wouldn't know.

Comment: I have been programming for a long time and I've never encountered this problem! lol. I can't think of a good reason for the behavior to be different for numbers.